# Is it possible to run two Linux commands in foreground and merge their stdout

Tags: linux, shell, command

I need to run 2 Linux commands that each does not exit and continue to output to stdout (until I `Ctrl-C` them).

I can run the 2 commands in 2 separate terminals without any issues.

However, can I issue one command in one terminal to run both of the commands above in foreground and have them share stdout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can express, and control this very simply with **GNU Parallel**. Let's say you create 2 dummy processes, `f1` and `f2` that just output repeatedly and never stop. They might look like this:

**f1**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   echo 1,$RANDOM
   sleep 2
done
```

**f2**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   echo 2,$RANDOM
   sleep 2
done
```

Now you can start both at once (obviously - it's not called **GNU Parallel** without reason) like this:

```
parallel --line-buffer ::: ./f1 ./f2
1,17387
2,1457
2,32743
1,15684
...
...
```

Or, if you want the lines of output tagged with the process name, you can do this:

```
parallel --line-buffer --tag ::: ./f[12]
./f1    1,11877
./f2    2,28716
./f2    2,7683
./f1    1,23392
...
...
```

If you Control-C the process, they will both stop - although you can change that if you wish - search for `--halt` on the manpage.

Comment: Did not know about this. Love it! I wish this was a built-in thing. Thanks!

Comment: **GNU Parallel** is sadly under-advertised and under-used. With the end of year-on-year CPU frequency increases and the start of the multi-core era, it is IMHO the way forward. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

You can run the first one on background and the second one on foreground they will share the stdout. With `Ctrl-C` you will be able to stop the 2nd one then if you want to stop the 1st you will have to kill the job. Press `fg` then `Ctrl-C`

```
cmd1 & cmd2
```

If you want to have a mix output file then

```
cmd1>file & cmd2>file
```

If you use `;` instead of `&` , the 2nd command will starts when the 1st finishes if you want a more readable output.

Not sure if you can run both at the same terminal and stop them together. Probably using an script or similar.

Comment: You might want to run the commands with `stdbuf` to merge their output line wise.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. This is actually not a bad option except that the user had to deal with a background process.

Answer (score -1):

Use curly braces:

```
{ command1; command2; } > output
```

if you want to redirect both stdout and stderr:

```
{ command1; command2; } &> output
```

Comment: This does not execute​ command2 until command1 finishes. But OP makes it clear that neither command terminates until killed, and that the intention is that both run in parallel.